# How to use the WP REST API with a custom endpoint using the Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, wp-api

I have a custom endpoint which does nothing but return a test string. I can reach that endpoint by navigating to `mydomain.com/wp-json/mytools/v1/method/get_user_data` and it correctly returns my test string, but, I want to be able to reach that endpoint using Javascript, and, I read that the wp-api handles authentication automatically so I should be able to get a current logged in user with this method.

What I need is to be able to use something like `wp.api.mytools.method.get_current_user`  and get the information for the currently logged in user. Is this even possible?

This is the way I created the endpoint:

```
    register_rest_route( 'mytools/v1', '/method/(?P<method>[\w]+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'invoke_method',
    ));
```

And this is the `invoke_method` function:

```
function invoke_method( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    return wp_get_current_user();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is already implemented by WordPress at the WP_REST endpoint '.../wp-json/wp/v2/users/me. In addition to the logged-in cookie WP REST authentication requires a nonce specified by a query argument '_wpnonce'. The value of this nonce is generated by calling wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ). A normal WordPress front-end page will include the script .../wp-includes/js/api-request.js. This script will define a global wpApiSettings.nonce which will contain this nonce so you can use the request '.../wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_wpnonce=' + wpApiSettings.nonce. So, you can use jQuery.get().

```
jQuery.get(
    '.../wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_wpnonce=' + wpApiSettings.nonce,
    function( response ) {
        var userData = JSON.parse( response );
    ) }
);
```

If you only want to get the current user I don't think you need Backbone.js. Backbone.js will synchronise collections and models using CRUD and you are not doing any of this.

Comment: The `wp_get_current_user()` part was just a placeholder, I'm trying to do several different stuff with this, but adding the `_wpnonce` param was what I needed, thanks!!

Comment: One last question... how can I accomplish the same but without using an ajax request? like, instead of sending a request to `'/wp-json/mytools/v1/method?_wpnonce=' + wpApiSettings.nonce`, doing something like `{whatever}.mytools.method`

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you directly use the WordPress REST API then you must send a HTTP request and since the response to this request is JSON and not HTML it should be processed by JavaScript. So, I think AJAX is necessary. Since, WordPress authentication requires the nonce the only way to avoid sending the nonce is to replace the WordPress authentication with your own but then authentication is your responsibility not WordPress's.

Comment: I mean that instead of me writing a `$.get( '/wp-json/mytools/do_this', {}, function(){})` request, being able to write it up like `wp.api.mytools.do_this`

Comment: I don't understand. Is 'wp.api.mytools.do_this' JavaScript, PHP or part of a URL?

Comment: If you use the Backbone.js client then the AJAX call will be done for when you do: var user = new wp.api.models.User( { id: 1 } ); user.fetch();

Comment: Are you trying to invoke generic functions on the WordPress server? The WP REST API and Backbone.js was not designed for this. It is a solution for representational state transfer (REST). It synchronises collections and models on the server with corresponding collections and models on the client. It doesn't directly support invoking a function but rather the CRUD ( create, read, update, and delete ) semantics on objects.

Comment: gotcha, that's what I was trying to accomplish, I will settle with the ajax call as you suggested in your answer.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Overall, yes, it IS possible.

Specifically, if `wp-api` if you're referring to the [node-wpapi JS library](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi), then yes it does handle authentication. Otherwise, you will need to implement Authentication yourself, using Cookie, Nonce, Basic-Auth or JWT.

For second part, it is definitely possible to use something like `wp.api.mytools.method.get_current_user` to get information. What you'll need is a client library (node-wpapi), and extend it to include your classes and functions, such as `mytools` and `method`.

Hope this helps to clarify

Comment: I'm actually referring to the included Backbone lib